# Read html select value into jenkins Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

`I am using Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter to get the option loaded based on the previous Active choice parameter(VMConfiguration). However I am able to get a dropdownlist getting just "Ver1", "Ver2", "Ver3".

````
ad_studio_install = [
 "AD Studio Install": 
  ["Ver1", "Ver2", "Ver3"] 
]

adstudio_list = ad_studio_install[VMConfiguration] 

html_to_be_rendered = """<select name="value">"""

adstudio_list.each { json_file ->
  html_to_be_rendered = """
    ${html_to_be_rendered}
    <option value="${json_file}">${json_file}</option>
"""
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the exact same problem a while back. As I could not get it to work with the Active Choice Parameter Plugin I wrote a plugin dedicated to this purpose. Having a sort of decision tree based choice in drop down boxes.
[image]

The only thing you need to do is install the "Multiselect Parameter" plugin and configure it to be used as a parameter in your build, like for example this way:

```
H,Software product,Selected version
V,SELECTED_SOFTWARE,SELECTED_VERSION
C,AD Studio,Ver1
C,AD Studio,Ver2
C,AD Studio,Ver3
```

In your build you get the selected values in the given environment variables `SELECTED_SOFTWARE` and `SELECTED_VERSION`.

You can even select human readable names for your versions and have a technical value in a variable.

All of this is explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/swesteme/multiselect-parameter-plugin) and in the help texts.

Comment: This is good. But this does not satisfy my requirement where the parameter should appear only if a particular option is selected from referenced parameter.

Comment: Its working now. I have missed the return statement at the end of the code.

Comment: Fair enough. Glad you solved it!